# No bad_alloc when creating two or more std::vector that together exceed the memory (MSVC)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, out-of-memory

I found out a strange incoherence when creating two vectors that together exceed the memory of the system (both physical and virtual):

```
int main() 
{
    std::size_t max_size_that_fits_memory = /*hardware-dependent value*/;

    std::vector<int> vec(max_size_that_fits_memory * 2); //OK: bad_alloc
}
```

`max_size_that_fits_memory` is an hardware-dependent value such that it doesn't throw a bad_alloc when instantiating a `std::vector<int> vec(max_size_that_fits_memory)`, but that it throws bad_alloc when instantiating `std::vector<int> vec(max_size_that_fits_memory * 2)`.
The above code results in a bad_alloc as expected, but

```
int main() 
{
    std::size_t max_size_that_fits_memory = /*...*/;

    std::vector<int> vec1(max_size_that_fits_memory); //Ok...
    std::vector<int> vec2(max_size_that_fits_memory); //Strange, no exception thrown
}
```

this piece instead doesn't throw any bad_alloc. The same behavior holds if I construct much more vectors of that size:

```
int main() 
{
    std::size_t max_size_that_fits_memory = /*...*/;

    std::vector<int> vec1(max_size_that_fits_memory);
    std::vector<int> vec2(max_size_that_fits_memory);
    //...
    std::vector<int> vecN(max_size_that_fits_memory);
}
```

How is it possible?

Comment: so what is the value of `max_size_that_fits_memory`?

Comment: Yeah.  This question is impossible to answer without knowing how you've decided what the "max size that fits in memory" is.  I'm also curious why you expect this to be the same on your local machine as on some random VM running in the cloud.

Comment: Win32 or Win64?

Comment: @VTT It's a value such that it doesn't throw a bac_alloc when instantiating `std::vector<int> vec(max_size_that_fits_memory)`, but that throws bad_alloc when instantiating `std::vector<int> vec(max_size_that_fits_memory * 2)`. It's hardware dependent, but the question, I think, it's hardware-independent.

Comment: @WernerHenze I'm on Win64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing with `vector` is that it requires memory to be allocated in *contiguous block*. A typical situation is when the total amount of free memory is sufficient but there is no contiguous block available. For example it possible to allocate multiple blocks of 3x cells, but not a single block of 6x cells here:

█░░░░░█░░░░█░░░██░░░░░█░░░░█░░░█

Comment: Thanks, I think that this answers most of my question. But something is still missing. Because on my system I have 16gb of physical memory and 15gb of virtual memory, but I can instantiate 10 or more vectors of 20gb each. How is it possible?

Comment: @Tarquiscani That would be another question. Typically amount of virtual memory is considerably greater than amount of physical memory. I think typical Win64 runs with at least 100Gb of virtual memory. Also are you sure that you don't have a swap file and that the program actually allocates those vectors and then exits gracefully?

Comment: Thanks for hint, I've been such a dumb. I oversaw that the program was stuck at initializing all that huge quantity of integers and didn't finish its execution. That's why no bad_alloc was thrown